# Getting VB written on Windows 1998 machine to run in windows vista/7?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm in a bit of a predicament here.  We have VB code written on a Windows 1998 machine that we need to run some calculations.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the mouse to work.  I think its a driver issue... but I can't solve the driver issue without using the mouse!!  Spent a while fumbling around with the keyboard to know avail.

Is it possible for me to get a very old version of the .net runtime working on a new computer (xp/vista/7)?  Or perhaps a virtual machine?

Comment: Poor youth, thinking you need a mouse to control a computer. Can't you save yourself with alt, shift, tab and space? Anyway Visual Basic from that era has little to do with .NET, which didn't even exist back then. Does the program not run under a newer OS, and if not, why not?

Comment: I wish I had NET in 1998 when I wrote those thousands of lines of messy code in VB6 that continue to haunt me

Comment: @CodeCaster Ha! Ironically I never, ever, ever use the mouse... on any linux distro with xmonad as a DE.  Don't know any of the Windows 98 key board shortcuts... wasn't alive in that era ;)  And it doesn't matter anyway because the VB program won't run without the mouse.

Comment: @CodeCaster - .NET 1.0 was available for Windows 98 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_1.0

Comment: In control panel, there's an accesibility option that allows to control the mouse using the arrow keys.

Comment: @the_lotus That could prove very, very helpful... thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a windows 98 machine you either need the .NET Framework 1.0 - available here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=96

Or you need the VB6 runtimes available here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887

Your mouse not working is nothing to do with VB - it is a driver issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'll download that on an new machine and see if it'll run there.  I know its a driver issue... I just can't fix it with the keyboard alone.